# Add extra margin on odd and even pages of two sided amsbook thesis

Tags: margins, amsbook

I'm writing a thesis using the `amsbook` class:

> `\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{amsbook}`

*How do I set up an extra 1 cm left or right margin on odd or even pages respectively?*

Comment: Have a look into the `geometry` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have problems with the marginal notes, if you use them. However, one centimeter for the binding is normally too much.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsbook}
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}

\calclayout % just to be on the safe side
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{1cm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-1cm}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Test}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This solution works well. How much extra margin do you think I should leave?

Comment: @Ryo Usually, 6 or 7 millimeters are enough.